# Computation of nearby cycles, monodromy action and action of $sl_{2}$ on $gr(\Psi)$ for Picard-Lefshetz family.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $f: \mathbb{A}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{1}$ be a map that sends $(x,y)$ to $xy$. Let $U \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^{2}$ be the preimage $f^{-1}(\mathbb{A}^{2}\setminus \{ 0\})$ and $X:=f^{-1}(0)$. Consider the shifted constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}_{U}[2]$ on $U$. Let $\Psi(\mathbb{C}_{U}[2])$ denote the nearby cycles functor applied to $\mathbb{C}_{U}[2]$. It gives us a perverse sheaf on $X$.

My question is: how to compute this perverse sheaf on $X$ and the action of monodromy on it? Also if the action is unipotent then how to calculate the action of "Lefshetz" $sl_{2}$ on $\operatorname{gr}(\Psi(\mathbb{C}_{U}[2]))$?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *compute* a perverse sheaf ? You can easily compute $H^i(\Psi(\mathbb{C}))$ in term of the standard $t$-structure. Is this what you want ? (Also I believe that this is $\Psi(\mathbb{C}[1])$ which is perverse, I might be wrong though, I am not an expert on perverse sheaves). Also, you take the graduate with respect to which filtration ? Monodromy ? Weight ? I wrote an answer but I have not posted yet since I may improve when I will know more precisely what you are asking.

Comment: But $U$ is smooth of complex dimension 2 thus I think that sheaf $\mathbb{C}_{U}[2]$ is perverse (not $\mathbb{C}_{U}[1]$). About filtration: there is a theorem of Gabber which says that two filtrations you mention coincide (for pure perverse sheaves --- to be more precise we deal with sheaf $\mathbb{C}_{U}[2](1)$). About what I mean to compute: actually, the most interesting for me is how $\operatorname{gr}(\mathbb{C}_{U}[2](1))$ looks like (as an object in the category of perverse sheaves). Thanks very much for response!

Comment: Sorry, $\operatorname{gr}(\Psi(\mathbb{C}_{U}[2](1)))$

Comment: $\mathbb{C}_U[2]$ is indeed perverse, but $\Psi$ does not preserve perverse sheaves whereas $\Psi[-1]$ does. But maybe you wrote $\Psi$ for what I call $\Psi[-1]$ (in some articles I saw the notation $\psi=\Psi[-1]$). And yes of course the two filtrations are the same here, you don't need a theorem of Gabber, this is quite obvious in this situation.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not writing it before, I consider shifted nearby cycles.

Comment: I am not sure how to write the graded part in the category of perverse sheaves, I use normal sheaves. I will post an answer, maybe you can complete it, or ask for precisions.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I am not an expert on perverse sheaves hence I am not sure I will completely answer the question.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ the two branches of $X$ ($x=0$ and $y=0$) and $O$ the point of intersection. In the following, everything will be on $X$, so when I write $\mathbb{C}_Z$ with $Z\subset X$ a closed subset, I mean $i_*\mathbb{C}$ the pushforward of the constant sheaf along the inclusion.

Finally, let $\omega_X$ be the dualizing sheaf on $X$ and $\Psi=\Psi(\mathbb{C}[2])$. (With the shifted nearby cycles functor).

We can resolve the constant sheaf on $X$ using the closed covering $X_1$ and $X_2$. We get a distinguished triangle in the derived category of $X$ :
$$\mathbb{C}_X\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}_{X_1}\oplus\mathbb{C}_{X_2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}_O\overset{+1}\longrightarrow$$
Dually, we get a distinguised triangle
$$\mathbb{C}_O\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}_{X_1}(1)[2]\oplus\mathbb{C}_{X_2}(1)[2]\longrightarrow\omega_X\overset{+1}\longrightarrow$$
In the above triangles, every map is a (sum or difference of) the canonical restriction/inclusion.

You have the following diagram with distinguished rows an column :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{}@.{}@.\mathbb{C}_{X_1}[1]\oplus\mathbb{C}_{X_2}[1]\\
@.@.@VVV\\
\mathbb{C}_O@>>>\Psi@>>>\omega_X(-1)[-1]@>{+1}>>\\
@VVV@|@VVV\\
\mathbb{C}_X[1]@>>>\Psi@>>>\mathbb{C}_O(-1)@>{+1}>>\\
@VVV@.@VV{+1}V\\
\mathbb{C}_{X_1}[1]\oplus\mathbb{C}_{X_2}[1]\\
@VV{+1}V
\end{CD}
$$
It is self dual.

The monodromy is unipotent, in fact $(T-1)^2=0$. The morphism $T-1$ is the composition $\Psi\rightarrow\mathbb{C}_O\rightarrow\Psi$. ($T-1$ happen to be shift by $(-1)$ but this is very exceptional)

The gr is given by $\operatorname{gr}\psi=\mathbb{C}_O \oplus \left(\mathbb{C}_{X_1}[1]\oplus\mathbb{C}_{X_2}[1]\right)\oplus\mathbb{C}_O(-1)$ and the monodromy induce an isomorphism between the weight 2 and the weight 0 part.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thanks! Only one question: is there a simple way to understand that rows are distinguished? (Probably I understand an argument: we need to compute vanishing cycles but they should be supported on the point $O$ and then from "classical" definition we see that vanishing cycles are of dimension 1 sitting in degree 0. After computing vanishing cycles we automatically get second distinguished row).

Comment: @Din Yes that's it, this is also how you get the monodromy. The first row is just the dual of the second but you can prove that it is distinguished using the same way.